# simple-html-dom nested

Tags: php, find, simple-html-dom

I am trying to use Simple HTML DOM to catch the last part of this pagination.
This part:

```
<a class="paginationNumberStyle page_arrows" data-url="**/Building-Materials/h_d1/N-5yc1vZ25ecodZaqns/h_d2/Navigation?catalogId=10053&amp;Nu=P_PARENT_ID&amp;langId=-1&amp;Nao=96&amp;storeId=10051**"> 


    <div class="page-nav">  

                <span>1</span>

                 <a class="paginationNumberStyle" data-url="/Building-Materials/h_d1/N-5yc1vZ25ecodZaqns/h_d2/Navigation?catalogId=10053&amp;Nu=P_PARENT_ID&amp;langId=-1&amp;Nao=96&amp;storeId=10051"> 
                    2
                 </a>

                 <a class="paginationNumberStyle" data-url="/Building-Materials/h_d1/N-5yc1vZ25ecodZaqns/h_d2/Navigation?catalogId=10053&amp;Nu=P_PARENT_ID&amp;langId=-1&amp;Nao=192&amp;storeId=10051"> 
                    3
                 </a>

                 <a class="paginationNumberStyle" data-url="/Building-Materials/h_d1/N-5yc1vZ25ecodZaqns/h_d2/Navigation?catalogId=10053&amp;Nu=P_PARENT_ID&amp;langId=-1&amp;Nao=288&amp;storeId=10051"> 
                    4
                 </a>

                 <a class="paginationNumberStyle" data-url="/Building-Materials/h_d1/N-5yc1vZ25ecodZaqns/h_d2/Navigation?catalogId=10053&amp;Nu=P_PARENT_ID&amp;langId=-1&amp;Nao=384&amp;storeId=10051"> 
                    5
                 </a>

        <a class="paginationNumberStyle page_arrows" data-url="/Building-Materials/h_d1/N-5yc1vZ25ecodZaqns/h_d2/Navigation?catalogId=10053&amp;Nu=P_PARENT_ID&amp;langId=-1&amp;Nao=96&amp;storeId=10051"> 
                    <img alt="" src="/static/images/layout/triangle-green-right.gif"></a>



</div>
```

Here is my code:

```
if ($nextPage = $dom->find('a[class=paginationNumberStyle.page_arrows]', 0)) {

   echo $nextPage->href;
```

I have also tried:

```
if ($nextPage = $dom->find('a[class=paginationNumberStyle.page_arrows]', 0)) {
```

I am far from an expert on Simple HTML DOM and was hoping that someone knew a quick answer. I am wondering if it is because of the data-url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity you can just:

```
$dom->find("a.page_arrows", 0)
```

Comment: pg... one more question how would I get the last occurence only?  (Youve seen my other question so you know where I am coming from).

Comment: It's the wrong approach because on the last page the last occurrence will be the previous link (because there will be no next link). I think you should start a new question for this showing html with both previous and next links.

Answer (score 1):

Try as this

```
if ($nextPage = $dom->find("a[class='paginationNumberStyle page_arrows]", 0)) echo $nextPage->getAttribute('data-url');
```

Comment: For me have worked :S, do you have some error or other? How you get the html?

Comment: this is the url 'http://www.homedepot.com/Building-Materials/h_d1/N-5yc1vZ25ecodZaqns/h_d2/Navigation?catalogId=10053&Nu=P_PARENT_ID&langId=-1&Nao=96&storeId=10051#/?c=1&style=List